# CSS vertical translation wrap as if top connected to bottom?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to write some CSS transitions where child elements of a container are translated from top to bottom and when they hit the bottom of the container they are reset to the top of the container just as if the bottom of the container was connected to the top of the container.

I was able to get the translation to work but I was not able to get the wrapping to work (or appear to work). The wrapping doesn't seem to occur until all elements fulfill the animation. Is this possible with CSS animations? Thanks!

Here is a link to the jsfiddle: [My fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m02n20bd/)

```js
function RainingCats() {
    this.svgHtml = null;
    this.width = window.innerWidth;
    this.COLOR_UPDATE_INTERVAL = 250; // ms
    this.$cats = [];
}

RainingCats.prototype.run = function() {
    var self = this;

    // Grab the template
    var $svgTemplate = $('#svgCatTemplate');

    // Update the color of each cat
    var colorInterval = null;

    this.V_MARGIN_PERCENT = 0.15;
    this.H_MARGIN_PERCENT = 0.15;
    this.svgHtml = $svgTemplate.html();
    this.svgWidth = $svgTemplate.width();
    this.svgHeight = $svgTemplate.height();

    function getColorInterval() {
        return setInterval(function() {
            for(var i = 0; i < self.$cats.length; i++) {
                var $cat = self.$cats[i];
                $('.head', $cat).attr('style', 'fill: ' + self.getRandomColor() + ';');
                $('.leftEye', $cat).attr('style', 'fill: ' + self.getRandomColor() + ';');
                $('.leftPupil', $cat).attr('style', 'fill: ' + self.getRandomColor() + ';');
                $('.rightEye', $cat).attr('style', 'fill: ' + self.getRandomColor() + ';');
                $('.rightPupil', $cat).attr('style', 'fill: ' + self.getRandomColor() + ';');
            }
        }, self.COLOR_UPDATE_INTERVAL);
    }

    // Update width if window is resized
    $(window).resize(function() {
        self.render();

        // Clear and reset interval
        clearInterval(colorInterval);
        colorInterval = getColorInterval();

        // Remove all the cats from the DOM
        self.$cats = [];
        $('#animationTarget').html('');

        // Recalculate sizing and draw cats
        self.render();

    });

    self.render();

    // Set the color interval to be stopped and reset on window resize
    colorInterval = getColorInterval();
};


RainingCats.prototype.getRandomColor = function() {
    var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
    var color = '#';
    for(var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
    }
    return color;
};

RainingCats.prototype.render = function(left, top) {
    var containerWidth = window.innerWidth;
    var containerHeight = window.innerHeight;
    var catHorizontalMargin = this.svgWidth * this.H_MARGIN_PERCENT;
    var catVerticalMargin = this.svgHeight * this.V_MARGIN_PERCENT;

    // Find maximum number of horizontal cats
    var maxHorizontalCats = Math.floor(containerWidth / ((catHorizontalMargin) + this.svgWidth));
    var maxVerticalCats = Math.floor(containerHeight / ((catVerticalMargin) + this.svgHeight));

    var maxWidth = (maxHorizontalCats * this.svgWidth) + ((maxHorizontalCats - 1) * catHorizontalMargin);
    var maxHeight = (maxVerticalCats * this.svgHeight) + ((maxVerticalCats - 1) * catVerticalMargin);

    function randRange(minNum, maxNum) {
        return(Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxNum - minNum + 1)) + minNum);
    }


    // Append all of the cats to the rain wrapper
    for(var r = 0; r < maxVerticalCats; r++) {
        for(var c = 0; c < maxHorizontalCats; c++) {

            var $cat = $('<div/>', {
                class: 'superCatContainer'
            }).css({
                width: this.svgWidth,
                height: this.svgHeight,
                top: ((containerHeight - maxHeight) / 2) + (r * this.svgHeight) + (r * catVerticalMargin),
                left: ((containerWidth - maxWidth) / 2) + (c * this.svgWidth) + (c * catHorizontalMargin),
                // background: this.getRandomColor()
            }).html(this.svgHtml);

            // Add the cat element to the cat array and then push to UI
            this.$cats.push($cat);
            $cat.appendTo($('#animationTarget'));
        }
    }


};



    $(document).ready(function() {
        new RainingCats().run();
    });
```

```css
body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    
    .animationContainer {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    @keyframes fall {
        to {
            margin-top: 100%
        }
    }
    
    .superCatContainer {
        display: inline-block;
        position: absolute;
        overflow: hidden;
        -webkit-animation: fall 2.5s linear infinite;
        -moz-animation: fall 2.5s linear infinite;
    }
    
    .svgCat {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        animation-duration: 2s;
        animation-name: spin;
        animation-iteration-count: infinite;
        animation-timing-function: linear;
    }
    
    @keyframes spin {
        from {
            transform: rotate(360deg);
        }
        to {
            transform: rotate(0deg);
        }
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="svgCatTemplate" style="display: none; width: 200px;height: 200px;">
        <svg class="svgCat" viewBox="0 0 499.11249 286.82501" width="499.11249" height="286.82501" xml:space="preserve">
            <g transform="matrix(1.25,0,0,-1.25,0,286.825)">
                <g transform="scale(0.1,0.1)">
                    <g clip-path="url(#clipPath18)">
                        <path class="head" d="m 1829.38,651.012 c -4.44,14.398 0.35,27.758 -5.24,39.59 -20.98,0.898 -41.68,2.578 -62.14,4.886 0.9,-18.519 4.93,-40.976 12.22,-64.59 17.17,-55.628 45.67,-96.187 63.67,-90.668 -6.36,-1.968 6.33,62.68 -8.51,110.782" inkscape:connector-curvature="0" style="fill:#100f0d;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none" />
                        <path class="head" d="m 2250.51,651.012 c -14.84,-48.102 -2.15,-112.75 -8.51,-110.782 18,-5.519 46.51,35.04 63.67,90.668 7.29,23.614 11.32,46.071 12.22,64.59 -20.46,-2.308 -41.16,-3.988 -62.14,-4.886 -5.58,-11.832 -0.8,-25.192 -5.24,-39.59" inkscape:connector-curvature="0" style="fill:#100f0d;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none" />
                        <path class="rightEye" d="m 2591.93,1140.14 c -61.03,0 -110.5,49.47 -110.5,110.5 0,61.04 49.47,110.51 110.5,110.51 61.04,0 110.51,-49.47 110.51,-110.51 0,-61.03 -49.47,-110.5 -110.51,-110.5 z m 20.07,320.84 c -90.92,0 -164.63,-90.82 -164.63,-202.87 0,-112.03 73.71,-202.86 164.63,-202.86 90.94,0 164.65,90.83 164.65,202.86 0,112.05 -73.71,202.87 -164.65,202.87" inkscape:connector-curvature="0" style="fill:#100f0d;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none" />
                        <path class="leftPupil" d="m 1440.95,1304.77 c -27.66,0 -50.09,-22.43 -50.09,-50.09 0,-27.67 22.43,-50.09 50.09,-50.09 27.65,0 50.09,22.42 50.09,50.09 0,27.66 -22.44,50.09 -50.09,50.09" inkscape:connector-curvature="0" style="fill:#100f0d;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none" />
                        <path class="leftEye" d="m 1431.93,1133.46 c -64.71,0 -117.17,52.46 -117.17,117.18 0,64.71 52.46,117.17 117.17,117.17 64.72,0 117.18,-52.46 117.18,-117.17 0,-64.72 -52.46,-117.18 -117.18,-117.18 z m -27.52,327.52 c -90.93,0 -164.64,-90.82 -164.64,-202.87 0,-112.03 73.71,-202.86 164.64,-202.86 90.92,0 164.64,90.83 164.64,202.86 0,112.05 -73.72,202.87 -164.64,202.87" inkscape:connector-curvature="0" style="fill:#100f0d;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none" />
                        <path class="rightPupil" d="m 2585.95,1304.77 c -27.66,0 -50.09,-22.43 -50.09,-50.09 0,-27.67 22.43,-50.09 50.09,-50.09 27.65,0 50.09,22.42 50.09,50.09 0,27.66 -22.44,50.09 -50.09,50.09" inkscape:connector-curvature="0" style="fill:#100f0d;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none" />
                        <path class="head" d="m 2612,942.012 c -141.68,0 -256.54,141.518 -256.54,316.098 0,174.59 114.86,316.12 256.54,316.12 141.7,0 256.57,-141.53 256.57,-316.12 0,-174.58 -114.87,-316.098 -256.57,-316.098 z m -244.63,-206 c 6.86,1.199 10.79,1.59 10.79,0.57 0,-165.23 -62.32,-351.871 -156.4,-465.352 -16.5,20.918 -32.8,32.321 -42.03,27.442 -11.19,-5.902 -8.54,-33.793 4.99,-66.852 -44.74,-41.14 -94.89,-65.75 -147.85,-65.75 -54.26,0 -105.51,25.961 -151.06,68.93 7.99,36.48 5.66,66 -6.77,69.84 -8.89,2.762 -20.91,-8.281 -32.15,-27.399 -87.91,109.879 -146.86,283.809 -150.99,441.52 -65.42,42.719 -108.7,116.551 -108.7,200.508 0,6.883 0.36,13.652 0.92,20.371 10.35,-122.629 113.11,-218.981 238.43,-218.981 79.57,0 150.05,38.891 193.56,98.653 43.52,-59.762 113.99,-98.653 193.58,-98.653 125.31,0 228.08,96.352 238.43,218.981 0.56,-6.719 0.92,-13.488 0.92,-20.371 0,-73.668 -33.31,-139.547 -85.67,-183.457 z m -962.96,206 c -141.69,0 -256.56,141.518 -256.56,316.098 0,174.59 114.87,316.12 256.56,316.12 141.69,0 256.55,-141.53 256.55,-316.12 0,-174.58 -114.86,-316.098 -256.55,-316.098 z m 619.16,89.728 c 91.58,0 165.81,-31.57 165.81,-70.49 0,-38.93 -74.23,-70.488 -165.81,-70.488 -91.54,0 -165.79,31.558 -165.79,70.488 0,38.92 74.25,70.49 165.79,70.49 z m 1428.31,224.61 c 238.3,0 444.14,-98.8 540.97,-241.94 -85.92,160.88 -304.61,275.27 -560.97,275.27 -30.24,0 -59.89,-1.75 -88.95,-4.83 -16.5,96.82 -50.91,186.58 -100.64,268.39 51.22,82.91 211.86,619.33 168.96,692.97 -93.15,159.92 -511.49,-136.52 -692.15,-277.51 -207.39,84.5 -452.51,130.23 -715.19,130.23 -267.26,0 -516.37,-47.29 -726.03,-134.63 -178.07,139.53 -614.259,449.24 -697.802,281.91 -42.898,-85.92 177.371,-706.39 177.402,-706.44 -45.722,-78.71 -77.441,-164.54 -92.918,-256.78 -33.664,4.26 -68.222,6.69 -103.878,6.69 -256.368,0 -474.766,-114.39 -560.684,-275.27 96.8359,143.14 302.234,241.94 540.547,241.94 40.613,0 80.449,-3.07 119.015,-8.56 -3.71,-30.71 -5.714,-62.08 -5.8,-94.12 -226.907,-17.93 -415.141,-125.92 -493.469,-272.58 90.469,133.71 275.566,228.7 493.84,240.63 0.34,-17.12 0.847,-34.07 1.648,-50.71 l 9.004,-108.76 C 773.027,75.4883 1647.28,0 2003.91,0 2371.93,0 3235.58,118.531 3343.04,969.41 l 9.25,110.08 c 0.63,13.6 1.08,27.35 1.39,41.23 211.71,-15.41 390.84,-109.04 479.19,-239.65 -76.56,143.37 -258.63,249.75 -478.79,271.22 -0.04,33.14 -2.15,65.54 -6.05,97.26 33.57,4.3 68.01,6.8 103.85,6.8" inkscape:connector-curvature="0" style="fill:#100f0d;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none" />
                    </g>
                </g>
            </g>
        </svg>
    </div>
    <div id="animationTarget" class="animationContainer"></div>
```